# Quicker way to \input and \newpage multiple times?

Tags: macros

I'm a college student so I mainly use tex for school work. and my main.tex typically looks like

```
\input{1}
\newpage
\input{2}
\newpage
\input{3}
\newpage
\input{4}
\newpage
\input{5}
\newpage
\input{6}
\newpage
\input{11}
\newpage
\input{12}
\newpage
\input{13}
```

I've tried using `\newcommand` to try to make this more compact, to no avail. Is it possible to have a command like `\inputmulti{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...}` and have it behave like above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a typical list processing request that can easily be handled by [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

% \inputmulti{<csv list>}
\newcommand{\inputmulti}[1]{%
  \renewcommand{\do}[1]{\newpage\input{##1}}% How each item will be processed
  \docsvlist{#1}% Process list
}

\begin{document}

\inputmulti{1,2,3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wowww.... One of the best suggestion...

Comment: awesome, thank you!